# Enforce transaction-local data dependencies in relational databases

Tags: transactions, relational-database, consistency, stm

In a simplified version of a problem, I have two transactions that update a single row:

```
UPDATE A SET X = 1
```

And

```
SELECT X FROM A
UPDATE A SET Y = 3
```

The problem is that we query `X` because there is data dependency on it for the correct value of `Y` but the actual formula it's not known up-front. It could be `Y = X + c` where `c` is user input.

Suppose that there is high contention on this row an most updates are independent so we want them to be concurrent whenever possible. Common approach of row versioning would introduce high rate of false conflicts as each transaction would check if previous version is unchanged.

How can an application express such data dependencies?

Would updating rows help to ensure this in general? For example:

```
SELECT X FROM A       -- returns X`
UPDATE A SET Y = 3

-- cause rollback if any concurrent transaction changes
-- any value within transitive closure of our local data dependencies
UPDATE A SET X = X`
```

Ideally, I hope that the same solution would work with `STM` approach where application would locally resolve most of the conflicts and issue a single update at a time.

Comment: Possible solution: A. Fekete, D. Liarokapis, E. O’Neil, P. O’Neil, and
D. Shasha. Making snapshot isolation serializable.

Comment: possible solution (implemented in Postgres): Michael J. Cahill , Uwe Röhm , Alan D. Fekete, Serializable isolation for snapshot databases

Comment: What's the WHERE condition for your UPDATE? Or are you updating the entire table?

Comment: I mentioned in question that WHERE clause would usually target a single row but I didn't want to specify what it would look like (it could be a subquery etc.). It could also be a range or (theoretically) entire table but that would defeat the intended optimization.

Comment: I find it had to understand what exactly you are after. If you want to enforce strict serialization of your updates, you need to do optimistic or pessimistic locking. If you are not happy with the resulting performance, then maybe you shouldn't use a relational database.